# what server commands should I use to get a solar eclipse to happen?

Tags: terraria

I know the eclipse is about 1 in 30 per day but what server commands can I use to cycle days? Should it be `midnight` then `dawn`, or `dusk` then `dawn` etc? Is it even possible to trigger via server commands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time the time turns to day, the world is in hardmode and a mechanical boss has been killed, there is a 1 in 25 chance of a solar eclipse taking place. For minimum time spent to get each solar eclipse, you would want to use `midnight`, wait for it to turn to daytime and see if you got one. While `dawn` sets the time to right when the day starts, it also skips the code that checks for solar eclipse and invasions.

Alternatively you could download [Tshock](http://tshock.co/xf/) server mod and use the command they provide to instantly start the solar eclipse event.